Server websocket in js and client websocket in java android
Hi I am trying to establish a connection between the WSS server written in JS and the WSS client written in Java but it keeps giving me a connection error where it says it failed to connect in 10 seconds
THIS IS THE SERVER :
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

// Load your SSL certificate and key
const server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'), // Your private key
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server.cert') // Your certificate
});

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
    console.log('Client connected');

    ws.on('message', (message) => {
        console.log('Received:', message);
        ws.send(`Echo: ${message}`); // Invia un messaggio di risposta
    });

    ws.on('close', () => {
        console.log('Client disconnected');
    });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('WebSocket server is running on wss://localhost:3000');
});


THIS IS THE CLIENT:
package com.example.webrtc;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.WebSocket;
import okhttp3.WebSocketListener;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okio.ByteString;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "WebSocketClient";
    private WebSocket webSocket;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create UnsafeOkHttpClient instance to bypass SSL verification
        OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();

        // Build the WebSocket request
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url("wss://192.168.10.179:3000").build();

        // Create a WebSocket listener
        WebSocketListener listener = new WebSocketListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "WebSocket opened");
                webSocket.send("Hello, Server!"); // Send a message to the server
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message from server: " + text);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message from server: " + bytes.hex());
            }

            @Override
            public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
                webSocket.close(1000, null);
                Log.d(TAG, "WebSocket closing: " + reason);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response) {
                Log.e(TAG, "WebSocket error: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        };

        // Connect to the WebSocket server
        webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);
    }

    // Method to create an Unsafe OkHttpClient to bypass SSL verification
    private OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {
        try {
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        @Override
                        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return new X509Certificate[0];
                        }
                    }
            };

            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
            final javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

            return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0])
                    .hostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true) // Accept all hostnames
                    .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}


I know that Android blocks WS and HTTP connections because they are not secure so I thought of making a WSS connection but I can't connect where I go wrong you have alternativesI know that Android blocks WS and HTTP connections because they are not secure so I thought of making a WSS connection but I can't connect where I go wrong you have alternatives.
